# Android Seekbar does not update no matter what I try

Tags: android, seekbar

Seekbar does not update, not sure if it's binder or other screw ups. I give up.

I have tried timer, runnable and it just would not update. I'm not sure if it's my fault or seekbar, I have no idea. I give up and I just want to ask the folks over at stackoverflow and see if you guys could help me. I've spent over 4 hours on this issue and it's just slowing down whatever else I could be doing.
here is what i've written for Runnable:

```
            public void run() {
                //int curr = player.mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
                try {
                    //why the dirty code?
                    //seekbar.setprogress did not work for me
                    //it refuses to update it's position
                    //i have no idea why and i have no time to look into it.
                    //I was throwing everything at the problem at this point.
                    Log.v("Service Bound", Integer.toString(curr));
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Service Bound!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    songStat.setProgress(0);
                    songStat.setMax(player.mediaPlayer.getDuration());
                    songStat.setProgress(100);
                    curr++;
                }catch(Exception e){

                }
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(r, 100);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this while initializing Handler, which will run your code on the main thread,

```
Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
```